# How to save a textfile with firefox add-on sdk?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

here is my main.js:

```
var widgets = require("sdk/widget");
var {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");
var promptSvc = Cc["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/prompt-service;1"].
    getService(Ci.nsIPromptService);
var stringtosave = 'secret information';

var widget = widgets.Widget({
    id: "save_text_button",
    label: "save text",
    contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
    onClick: function() {
        promptSvc.alert(null, "My Add-on", stringtosave + " saved! ");
    }
});
```

It can alert the string using XPCOM.

How can I save the stringtosave in a textfile somewhere on the PC's harddrive?

Maybe there is a simple solution, that also makes use of XPCOM.

Comment: by the way this code works great and is a good tutorial for using XPCOM from add-on sdk. The button should appear in the bottom right corner of the browser. And it is very easy to get it run, as this main.js is all you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you want to use the profile directory

```js
const { pathFor } = require('sdk/system');
const path = require('sdk/fs/path');
const file = require('sdk/io/file');

function saveText(name, str){
  var filename = path.join(pathFor('ProfD'), name);
  var textWriter = file.open(filename, 'w');
  textWriter.write(str);
  textWriter.close();
}

function readText(name){
  var filename = path.join(pathFor('ProfD'), name);
  if(!file.exists(filename)){
    return null;
  }
  var textReader = file.open(filename, 'r');
  var str = textReader.read();
  textReader.close();
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to paa's great answer I can post my enhanced main.js:

```
var widgets = require("sdk/widget");
var {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");
var promptSvc = Cc["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/prompt-service;1"].
    getService(Ci.nsIPromptService);
var stringtosave = 'secret information';

//---------------------
const { pathFor } = require('sdk/system');
const path = require('sdk/fs/path');
const file = require('sdk/io/file');

function saveText(name, str){
    var filename = path.join(pathFor('ProfD'), name);
    var textWriter = file.open(filename, 'w');
    textWriter.write(str);
    textWriter.close();
}

function readText(name){
    var filename = path.join(pathFor('ProfD'), name);
    if(!file.exists(filename)){
        return null;
    }
    var textReader = file.open(filename, 'r');
    var str = textReader.read();
    textReader.close();
    return str;
}
//--------------------


var widget = widgets.Widget({
    id: "save_text_button",
    label: "save text",
    contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
    onClick: function() {
        var stringtoshow = readText('secret_message.txt');
        console.log('this message was saved before: '+stringtoshow);

        saveText('secret_message.txt',stringtosave);

        promptSvc.alert(null, "My Add-on", stringtosave + " saved! ");

    }
});

console.log('path: '+pathFor('ProfD'));
```